# Jquery slider for wordpress, random, with featured slide, editable

Tags: jquery, wordpress, content-management-system, slider

I've been on a search for a while for a WP jQuery slider with the following options:

1. Has default slide that appears first every time someone lands on a page.
2. Rest of the slide need to be randomized.
3. Needs to be 100% editable from the admin section for users with no knowledge of html/css/js.
4. Needs arrow navigation + bullets.

I haven't been able to find one that can support a featured default image, then randomize the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of free and commercial plugins are on web to use. If you are confused about choosing a great plugin for your website then check following plugins:

**Smooth Slider** is a WordPress Plugin for creating a dynamic slideshow for featured posts on a blog. The slideshow created by Smooth Slider are JavaScript and Text based, that’s why bloggers and site owners will get full benefit of Search Engine Optimization as the texts are readable by Search Engine.
Link: http://slidervilla.com/smooth-slider/

**vSlider** is a jQuery based image slider plugin for WordPress. It is one of most popular image slider plugin with over 50,000 downloads. It can be used as header slider, category slider, post slider , slideshow or custom image gallery.
Link: http://www.vibethemes.com/vslider-wordpress-plugin/

**Dynamic Content Gallery:** Creates a dynamic gallery of images for latest or featured content posts, categories, pages and Custom Post Type posts.
Link: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dynamic-content-gallery-plugin/

**WP Parallax Content Slider:** A customizable JQuery content slider with CSS3 animations and parallax effects.
Link: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-parallax-content-slider/

**Genesis Responsive Slider:** This plugin allows you to create a simple responsive slider that displays the featured image, along with the title and excerpt from each post.
Link: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/genesis-responsive-slider/

You can also **buy some great plugins** from http://codecanyon.net/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=wordpress+slider

May be it can help you.
Thanks.